# How to get URI from filename which is saved in the external Storage using Scoped Storage in android 10 and above?

Tags: android, local-storage, android-10.0, android-external-storage, scoped-storage

Before SDK 29 this is the correct way to find the Uri but now it won't work anymore for sdk greater than 28. **Let's assume I save the BITMAP using scoped-storage like:**

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
@NonNull
private Uri saveBitmap(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final Bitmap bitmap,
                       @NonNull final Bitmap.CompressFormat format, @NonNull final String mimeType,
                       @NonNull final String displayName, @Nullable final String subFolder) throws IOException {
    String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES;

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(subFolder)) {
        relativeLocation += File.separator + subFolder;
    }

    final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);

    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

    OutputStream stream = null;
    Uri uri = null;

    try {
        final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues);

        if (uri == null) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");
        }

        stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);

        if (stream == null) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to get output stream.");
        }

        if (!bitmap.compress(format, 95, stream)) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to save bitmap.");
        }

        return uri;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (uri != null) {
            // Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
            resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
        }

        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works for SDK <= 28. **But, How to get URI using fileName which is saved in the external storage for SDK version 29 and above?**

```
private String getFilePathUri(String enteredFileName) {

    String file_uri_string = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
            + AppConstants.APP_FOLDER + "/" + enteredFileName + ".jpg";
    AppUtils.showLog(TAG, file_uri_string + "");
    return file_uri_string;

}
```

Comment: According to Commonsware in his book.Notably, the methods on Environment like getExternalStorageDirectory() and getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() are deprecated. And, if you try to use those directories, you will find that your app lacks access, even if you hold READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. You can add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=" true" to the <application> element in the manifest to say that you want the “legacy” storage model. This will help you to access the storage app running on Android 10.

Comment: Your first code block should work for Q/29. But we cannot see the value of your folder and path variabled. Please add them to your post.

Comment: Would be great if anyone can help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63480192/how-to-save-and-store-pdf-file-in-a-folder-using-scoped-storage-in-android-10-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android 10 and above:** Here the uri gives the file_id based you the given displayName.

```
/**
 * Returns the Uri which can be used to delete/work with images in the photo gallery.
 * @param displayName Path to IMAGE on SD card
 * @return Uri in the format of... content://media/external/images/media/[NUMBER]
 */
private Uri getUriFromPath(String displayName) {
    long photoId;
    Uri photoUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external");

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID};
    // TODO This will break if we have no matching item in the MediaStore.
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, projection, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?", new String[] { displayName }, null);
    assert cursor != null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    photoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

    cursor.close();
    return Uri.parse(photoUri.toString() + "/" + photoId);
}
```

Comment: There can be more files with the same name in different directories. How do you handle that?

Comment: You can query using relative path.